# How can I resolve datatable button conflict

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable. I want to add a button to this datatble, but I ran into a problem. When I add the button, the search and pagination are all gathered in one place, as in the picture. It fixes itself when I remove the button. How can i solve this problem.

The problem I'm having is as follows, I used dom elements but I couldn't solve it
[image]

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#kisitListesi').DataTable(
                {
                   
                    "dom": 'Blfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: 'My button',
                            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                                alert('Button activated');
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "language": {
                        "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Turkish.json"
                    },
                  
                }
            );
        });
```

Comment: Please provide a complete snippet (see [mcve]) the [SO wiki for datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) provides some starter code.   Please also be sure to specify the exact version of datatables (I'll guess at 1.10.20 given the lang).  I tried your code, but your button didn't show: https://jsfiddle.net/2dgso64w/

Comment: [Datatable semanticui](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/semanticui.html) I use this. For the button do this [Button.js](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/semanticui.html)

Comment: [The documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) has instructions on how to integrate with your styling framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with different `wide` values, but here is one approach, where the buttons are in this section:

```
<'two wide column'B>
```

The full `dom` option:

```
    dom: "<'ui stackable grid'"+
           "<'row'"+
             "<'two wide column'B>"+
             "<'six wide column'l>"+
             "<'right aligned eight wide column'f>"+
           ">"+
           "<'row dt-table'"+
             "<'sixteen wide column'tr>"+
           ">"+
           "<'row'"+
             "<'seven wide column'i>"+
             "<'right aligned nine wide column'p>"+
           ">"+
         ">",
```

In the above example, the numbers in each row add up to 16 (e.g. `two`, `six` `eight`). You may need to adjust these to make the display look acceptable for your specific table sizing.

---

A runnable demo - but make sure you run it in **full page width** to see the unstacked alignment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: "<'ui stackable grid'" +
      "<'row'" +
      "<'two wide column'B>" +
      "<'six wide column'l>" +
      "<'right aligned eight wide column'f>" +
      ">" +
      "<'row dt-table'" +
      "<'sixteen wide column'tr>" +
      ">" +
      "<'row'" +
      "<'seven wide column'i>" +
      "<'right aligned nine wide column'p>" +
      ">" +
      ">",
    buttons: [{
      text: 'My button',
      action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
        alert('Button activated');
      }
    }],
    language: {
      url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Turkish.json"
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fomantic-ui/2.8.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/dataTables.semanticui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/css/buttons.semanticui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/dataTables.semanticui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.semanticui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fomantic-ui/2.8.8/semantic.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="class=" ui celled table " style="width:100% ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office in Country</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```